# Javascript comparison behaving differently in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, browser

Here is a portion of my javascript code

```
    var dataList = eval(strArray[0]); 
    for (i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
       console.log(((dataList[i].isFollowed == 0) ? "Follow" : "UnFollow"));
    }
```

But this code behaves differently in different browsers.For the below json data

```
[{"UserId":1,"Name":"John","isFollowed":1},{"UserId":2,"Name":"","isFollowed":0}
```

In chrome  it prints `UnFollow Follow`
But in mozilla and other browsers it prints `Follow Follow`

Can some one throw some light why its happening??

Comment: In which way they behave differently?

Comment: for what purpose are you using `eval()` ?

Comment: Maybe CSS or something else is the reason you see different behavior? Post a jsFiddle with your problem and you will get an answer

Comment: @Spokey Probably for parsing the JSON.

Comment: It works fine for me in the Firebug console.

Comment: eval() is evil...please avoid that

Comment: "jquery is evil" ... sorry what I meant to say is, why have you tagged your question `jquery` when it clearly is not? If you change `eval` to `$.parseJSON`, no-one will comment on `eval` is `evil` anymore, as it will be hidden magically in the jquery library by `function evaluation` is `little less evil` and your jquery tag will be correct :)

Comment: [MDN JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: only local eval is evil (for same reasons as `with`), `new Function` is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the code in 4 browsers, Chromium v25, Google Chrome v27, FireFox v21 and Opera v12.14 an all gave the result `UnFollow Follow`. Which browsers are you saying are inconsistent?

Javascript

```
 var dataList = [{
     "UserId": 1,
     "Name": "John",
     "isFollowed": 1
 }, {
     "UserId": 2,
     "Name": "",
     "isFollowed": 0
 }];

 for (i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
     console.log(((dataList[i].isFollowed == 0) ? "Follow" : "UnFollow"));
 }
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/SmsBD/)